# Neptune AWS Gremlin Docs for Next()

Tags: amazon-web-services, gremlin, amazon-neptune

this might be a basic question, but I cannot find the docs anywhere for this for the life of me.  I tried https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#terminal-steps but for the terminal steps it seems to be only for gremlin console.

I'm running gremlin in javascript on an AWS lambda connecting to neptune. What do the things next() returns mean?

I call something like

```
const addedItem = await g.addV('student').property('name', 'Jeffery').property('GPA', 4.0).next();
console.log('added: ' + mapToStr(addedItem));
```

this outputs

```
added: {"value":{"id":"24c52605-36ce-3194-72d6-46f5265ac59e","label":"student"},"done":false}
```

Value is self explanatory (even though if I want the full item back I have to add .valueMap()), what does "done" mean?  Does it mean neptune has not yet added the node yet? I have noticed sometimes when I run my script back-to-back I get

`Failed to complete Insert operation for a VertexProperty due to conflicting concurrent operations. Please retry. 0 transactions are currently rolling back.`

Comment: The fact that you got an ID back means the `addV` worked. I'm not sure about the `"done":false` but I don't use the javascript client too much. I'll see what else I can find out if no one beats me to it! The error about conflicting operations usually happens if you have concurrent operations touching the same (or nearby) parts of the graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the `next()` being called is the JavaScript method, not the Gremlin step (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-generator-next-method/) where the `done` field represents the fact that the iterator has additional items that can be returned.  Usually when I work in JavaScript I use the `toList()` gremlin step as the terminal step which returns all values as a list instead of as an iterator like the `next()` step.  Unless you are returning many values, you will not see any noticeable performance difference

Comment: Thanks!  I think it is calling the gremlin step actually, but it just happens to have the same definition as the javascript one it seems like it's based on it.  I found this in gremlin github's traversal.js

  /**
   * Async iterator method implementation.
   * Returns a promise containing an iterator item.
   * @returns {Promise.<{value, done}>}
   */
  next() {
    return this._applyStrategies().then(() => this._getNext());
  }